# Python running a script both from inside and outside the package

Tags: python-3.7

Continuing my quest to really understand modules and packages in Python 3.7, here's a simplified scenario which I am having trouble understanding:

./modtest/test1.py

```
from test2 import C, y

def x(i):
    print(i)
    a = C()
    y(i)

x(1000)
```

./modtest/test2.py:

```
def y(i):
    print(i)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C")
        pass
```

./testmodtest.py (outside of the modest package)

```
import modtest.test1
test1(1)
```

When running testmodtest from pwd = ./ I get an error, No Module named 'test2' generated from test1.py.

I am able to run test2 when pwd = ./modtest

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is it possible to write a module (e.g. testmodtest.py) so that it can be run from inside as well as outside the module?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

- In `test1.py`:
  When using a bare module name in an import statement, Python looks for that module [in three places](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path): (1) the current working directory, (2) the directories in the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), and (3) the default package directory (e.g. `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`). This is why `from test2 import ...` does not work when `test2.py` is not in any of these places. However, when your modules are in a common package, they can import each other using [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). The following therefore works, because the dot `.` tells Python to look for `test2` relative to the package which contains `test1.py`:

  ```py
  from .test2 import C, y
  ```

  However, this only works when `test1.py` is not run as a script (i.e. it is merely imported by another script).
- In `testmodtest.py`:
  The `test1(1)` does not work, because you've imported `test1` as `modtest.test1`. Moreover, `test1` is not callable, because it is a module -- I'm assuming you meant to call `test1.x`, which is a function. So, either of the following would work:

  ```py
  import modtest.test1
  modtest.test1.x(1)
  ```

  ```py
  from modtest import test1
  test1.x(1)
  ```

Another possibility would be to *install* your `modtest` package (which basically means copying it to the default package directory), for example by creating a [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) script and [installing it using `pip`](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html). If you do that, you can do `import modtest.test2` from any working directory, and, since you're not using relative imports anymore, you can also run all of the modules in the package as scripts (e.g. `python modtest/test1.py`).